# jQuery scroll One page-nav menu Bug

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm experiencing a bug with my navigation menu, which work fine when you load the page, after you click on a navigation page it scrolls to the specific point and it also ads an active class to the li, so it looks highlighted(active) but after I open a different page and then click on any navigation link from the menu, it is supposed to go back to the home page which it does, but it seems to have a problem getting the position for the section and adding the active class to it. I really appreciate any help on this, here's the link to the site:

http://staging.creativemagma.com/trinity/

load the site, test the navigation, then open a bio post and click on any of the links from the navigation to experience the problem.

Comment: The problem seems to occur when accessing the main page with a url that includes the pages #tag . I.E. http://staging.creativemagma.com/trinity/#projects-section

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when user is on homepage scrolling to exact point is processed via jQuery and when user gets to the homepage from other pages using link like - http://staging.creativemagma.com/trinity/#about scrolling on it is yet controlled only by native browser methods - which only shows an element with needed ID in the viewport

To correct this you'll have to add this to your jquery code:

```
$('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($('.anchor#'+document.location.href.split('#')[1])).offset().top
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
```

After page is loaded we get url hash and search for an element(span.anchor) with following id and scroll the whole document to it

Comment: Hi thanks for your help that didn't seem to fix it, I added it but it keeps the #url and every time I click on the different section seems to go back to the previous one.